Find all positive integers $a,b > 1$ that satisfy: $b^a\mid a^b-1$

Find all positive integers $a,b > 1$ that satisfy:
$$b^a\mid a^b-1.$$

If I let $p$ be the biggest prime divisor of $b$, I get $$ord_p(a)\mid b$$ $$ord_p(a)\mid\space p-1.$$
Then $ord_p(a)=1$ so $p\mid a-1$,
and I got stuck.

Yes, use a\mid b for $a\mid b.$

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta.

For equality $a^b-1=b^a$ we obtain $(a,b)=(3,2),(2,1)$, see this post.

Using an Approach0 search, in addition to Dietrich's post for the equality case, there's also Solving a Diophantine Equation with 2 variables, which I've just now closed as a duplicate. For your specific question, there are also the AoPS threads Find all integer and Maybe hard number theory (which gives a source of "VMF", and being in the "High School Olympiads" section).
